# Google Home Control custom device types and traits

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I'm trying to control an unsupported device type through Smart Home actions on Google. I would need custom commands such as fan speed, away mode, and scheduling. Is there any way to create custom device types and traits using the actions SDK and through Home Control? Also is there a way to pull room information from the Home Control app and modify it in my own app? The goal would be to create rooms in my own app, but still be able to say "Turn on fans in my bedroom".

Answer (score 0):

1) Unfortunately there's no custom device support

2) There's no API to query or set room information from the HomeGraph. Device rooms are set explicitly by the user in the Assistant mobile app.